# Apache rewrite redirecting to Amazon Linux AMI Test Page

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, amazon-web-services, url-rewriting

I have a java app that runs on apache tomcat. I have the following rewrite rule.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mydomain.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !/httpstatus https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

For some reason, the application is being redirected to the Amazon Linux AMI Test Page rather than my application. I'm assuming the context is being striped, but I'm not a linux expert and really don't know for sure.

What would cause this error?

Comment: Do you have an Elastic Load Balancer in front of Apache? Or something else setting the X-Forwarded-Proto header? If not you should remove the RewriteCond line.

Comment: Yes I have an Elastic Load Balancer.

Comment: Do you know if I should be doing this rewrite in the httpd.conf file or the elasticbeanstalk.conf file?

Comment: Also, I'm now seeing this in my log "File does not exist: /var/www/html/httpstatus". This is a tomcat application, so that doesn't make sense to me why it would be looking there for that file

Comment: What are you using to forward requests to Tomcat? Did you configure mod_proxy or mod_jk?

Comment: @DavidLevesque I was able to get things working, however I'm not sure it was the correct approach for the reasons described in my answer. If you have a quick minute, you you mind taking a quick glance at my answer? I'm trying to redirect to https from http.

Comment: Looks good. Config files under `conf.d` and `httpd.conf` itself all get included into one big config file at the end. The order of inclusion matters however since repeated directives can override each other (the last one wins). Maybe including it in elasticbeanstalk.conf changed that order somehow, I'm not sure. Anyhow, if it works, it works.

Answer (score 1):

So I got things working, however I'm not sure this is the absolute correct answer to the problem. I was under the impression that the URL would just be redirected to https, but the request would still be forwarded off to tomcat over 8080. When I did an output on the port within the app, it was seeing 443. Anyhow my code is below.

Rather than adding my rewrite to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` as most sites describe to do, found I had to add it to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
  TransferLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule !/httpstatus  https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite-error_log
  TransferLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite-access_log

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was racking my brains! I'll start of saying first that your file works.  That said, I had to take an extra step after upload/deployment in elastic beanstalk console:

**SSH into my ec2 instance and do "sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart"**

I'm a noob at this, so I'll share my thoughts/questions while going through the reroute process.

A lot of stackoverflow questions have answers/comments stating that the ELB will fail health check after reroute.  Mine seems to be fine with the rules above after adding a page status.html and adding it to my controller. So RewriteRule !/status  https://%{SER....  works.

- go to EC2 Dashboard >> "load balancers" (on left) >> [Health Check] tab >> [edit health check button] >> drop down to http and enter "/status" in the "ping path" box.  ("status" can be whatever you want as long as it's an always reachable page in your app/website" .. i just put some text in my status.html)
  = The above I thought was important because it wasn't all obvious while going through this and the pics in the AWS docs don't reflect how it looks as of today.

As a noob, I wondered if I had to replace {SERVER_NAME} with my actual server name, or with my site www.example.com... I didn't. so the line as it is above is fine as it is.

**[This tutorial](http://msnider.github.io/blog/2013/12/06/force-https-slash-ssl-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk/)  helped a bunch.** You don't have to SSH in and use vim to modify your elasticbeanstalk.conf. If it's not obvious, your literally going to make a folder named ".ebextensions" such that, once the war is created, your .ebextensions folder is at the root (same level as your META-INF and WEB-INF).